# Fragment : void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View) on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

Since the crash is coming from internal library of android and the most suspected code is below, this crash is coming in Oreo devices only

```
ChatAlertDialogFragment chatAlertDialogFragment = ChatAlertDialogFragment.getInstance(bundle);
chatAlertDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), ChatAlertDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

**NOTE**: When we replace simple fragment manager with the support fragment manger then it works fine.

This is the exception log

```
07-18 14:59:45.103 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aspiringminds.amcat.debug, PID: 13679
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewAt(ViewGroup.java:5170)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1561)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1611)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2204)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2148)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2049)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:718)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

`ChatAlertDialogFragment` class code

```
public class ChatAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
  public static ChatAlertDialogFragment getInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    ChatAlertDialogFragment chatAlertDialogFragment = new ChatAlertDialogFragment();
    chatAlertDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
    chatAlertDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return chatAlertDialogFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.setStyle(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    return dialog;
  }
}
```

Comment: Added ChatAlertDialogFragment Code here.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur updated the code and this crash is coming on Oreo